# Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in ssis

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am running a SSIS package that calls an SP form Mysql DB via a SP.

1. Get a list of values in a sql server table.
2. pass each value as a parameter to an SP in mysql.
3. Once the SP returns data, insert it into a table in sql server after suitable data conversions.

When the SP returns data, the package runs fine. However when the SP returns 0 rows then the package fails with the error:

```
[ADO NET Source 1 1 [126]] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper).
```

My expectation is the package should succeed, not insert any rows into the table if the SP returns 0 rows.

I mean why is it throwing an exception in ADO NET Source...

Note, the package succeeds if the SP returns more than 0 rows.

Workarounds are also welcome.

Comment: Well, the most obvious answer: Why don't you rewrite your SP in SQL Server? Besides that, have you tried playing around with the connection manager? IIRC there's an option concerning NULL values. Or maybe you can also ignore NULL values / errors.

Comment: I tried creating a linked server and then called the SP from SQL server. Still got the error: "Cannot process the object "CALL Person_Commit ('ITS:ITS-005368_jsp')". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL_SONAR" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object"

Comment: You want me to write an SP in sql server to get data from MYSQL.. can you please provide a link to such an article. Not sure where there is an option for null values in a connection manager.

Comment: Can't you alter the code to validate if 0 rows are returned and only proceed if returned rows are greater than 0?